# Relating Tables in CartoDB

Tags: carto

Is there a way to relate tables in CartoDB?

More specifically, is there a way to have a single row in one table associated with multiple rows in another table without having to actually join them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply a SQL query and use it to create your map, just apply the desired SQL involving the tables in SQL window (right toolbar)